# Not able to create External Content Type in SharePoint Designer 2013 using Stored Procedure

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, external-list, sql-server-2012

I want to create the external content type using stored procedure but it is giving me error such that, when I right click on routines in *Data Source Explorer* and then select *New Read Item Operation* then it is giving error as

> "Invalid Object Name"

Why does that happen so? Whereas some of the routines, stored procedures are connecting successfully. It is creating problem due to the schema which is dbo.Information. Whereas it is hawing the name as "Information" in SharePoint Designer 2013. Stuck to the issue, unable to get, how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is solved there was problem with name of the database table name in the stored procedure. Just passed name dw.TimeSheet_FK which was database table name instead of dbo.information, the problem was solved then.